# Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected in shiny and rmarkdown

Tags: r, json, shiny, r-markdown, shinyapps

I am creating a shiny app that takes input of a json file and sends it to rmarkdown file through params to create a pdf. THe problem is that when rmarkdown file is run idependently, it finished task without error but when the file is sent through shiny app as params, it shows the error "Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected",.  Following is the REPREX example of shiny app (ui.R and server.R) and Rmd file:

**This is ui.R file:**

```
library(pagedown)
library(tinytex)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(coreNLP)
library(syuzhet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(RJSONIO)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(wordcloud2)
library(dtt)
library(showtext)
library(patchwork)
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("CustomerLytics"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("jsonfile","UPLOAD JSONFILE",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c(".JSON"), 
                buttonLabel = "Upload Json File", 
                placeholder = "No Json File Uploaded"),
      
      # Show a pdf
      
      downloadButton("report", "Generate CustomerLytics PDF Report")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="CustomerLytics4Shiny.pdf")
      
    )
  )
)
```

**This is server.R file:**

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = "CustomerLytics4Shiny.pdf",
    
    content = function(file) {
      
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "Reprex.Rmd")
      file.copy("Reprex.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(file = input$jsonfile)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file, output_format = "pdf_document",
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
      detach("package:kableExtra", unload=TRUE)
    }
  )
}
```

**This is Rmd file:**

````
---
author: "created by CUSTOMERLYTICS"
date: \today
fontsize: 13pt
params:
  logo: F:/arun/R/nlpPROJECTS/NLPPROJECT/CustomerlyticsAPI/CustomerLyticsremovebg.png
  license: "CC-BY-SA"
  multicols: 3
  reduce_space_before_code: false
  col_title: "8B8B83"
  col_sections: "000000"
  col_code: "014979"
  col_headerbox: "FBEFCE"
  col_redbox: "C34A47"
  col_whitebox: "e0e0e0"
  file: NA
  cmede: "123"
  cklant: "001"
  nmede: "Rocks"
  nklant: "Kelly"
header-includes: 
  # if you include a logo, don't remove this line!!
  - \newcommand{\logo}{`r gsub("_", "\\_", params$logo)`}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{background}
  - \backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=0.4,angle=0,pages=each,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{F:/arun/R/nlpPROJECTS/NLPPROJECT/CustomerlyticsAPI/washedout.jpeg}}}
output:
  UHHformats::pdf_cheatsheet:
    highlight: "kate"
    font: "TheSansUHH"
always_allow_html: true
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.align="center")


library(pagedown)
library(tinytex)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(coreNLP)
library(syuzhet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(RJSONIO)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(wordcloud2)
library(dtt)
library(showtext)
library(patchwork)

# font_add(
#   "OpenSans",
#   "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
# )

```

```{r uploadJSONFile, echo=FALSE}

#file=params$file

file=jsonlite::fromJSON("F:\\arun\\R\\nlpPROJECTS\\CustomerlyticsAPI\\CustomerLyticsMarch2023\\CustomerLyticsApp\\www\\Gesprek1JW.json")

```


```{r json-dataprocessing,echo=FALSE}

##########################################################
  # Uploading json file
  # Separating S0 and S1 dataframes


# df_S0_=params$file[[1]][[1]]
# 
# df_S1_=params$file[[1]][[2]]

S0=file$words[1]

S0=S0[[1]]

df_S0_=S0

S1=file$words[2]

S1=S1[[1]]

df_S1_=S1

 ##########################################################
 #
 ########### Data manipulation from char to numeric
 #

w0= as.character(df_S0_$word) 
  
  tt0= as.numeric(df_S0_$totaltime) 
  
  wt0= as.numeric(df_S0_$wordtime) 
  
  bt0= as.numeric(df_S0_$begin_timestamp) 
  
  et0= as.numeric(df_S0_$end_timestamp) 
  
  c0= as.numeric(df_S0_$confidence) 
  
  s0= as.character(df_S0_$speaker) 
  
  df_S0= cbind.data.frame(word=w0, totaltime=tt0, wordtime=wt0,   
                          begin_timestamp=bt0, etimestamp=et0,
                          confidence=c0, speaker=s0) 
  
  w1= as.character(df_S1_$word) 
  
  tt1= as.numeric(df_S1_$totaltime) 
  
  wt1= as.numeric(df_S1_$wordtime) 
  
  bt1= as.numeric(df_S1_$begin_timestamp) 
  
  et1= as.numeric(df_S1_$end_timestamp) 
  
  c1= as.numeric(df_S1_$confidence) 
  
  s1= as.character(df_S1_$speaker) 
  
  df_S1= cbind.data.frame(word=w1, totaltime=tt1, wordtime=wt1,
                          begin_timestamp=bt1,etimestamp=et1,
                          confidence=c1, speaker=s1) 
 
```
````

When I run the App, it quits between line 82-365. In reprex verson, I reduced number of lines to 149 but still it shows quitting between 86-365 lines. Let me know what is wrong with it...

I have tried solutions related to this available but there is no example which involves shiny and rmd combination.